# Forward mail to multiple recipients with exim4

Tags: exim

I use a server to forward email sent to various domains to the appropriate users' main inboxes. I've got a fairly standard exim installation with the following major change to the configuration:

```
domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/domains.list

sender_redirect:
    driver = redirect
    domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/domains.list
    data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/virtual/domains/$domain}}

catchall_redirect:
    driver = redirect
    domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/domains.list
    data = ${lookup{postmaster}lsearch{/etc/virtual/domains/$domain}}
```

The file `/etc/virtual/domains.list` contains a list of all the domains my server handles mail for, and `/etc/virtual/domains/` contains files names according to the domain they pertain to, like `/etc/virtual/domains/example.com`. Each of those files is formatted like so:

```
postmaster: me@gmail.com
someuser: address@yahoo.com
otheruser: kittens@aol.com
```

...and so on. This configuration works as intended. If the user is found in `/etc/virtual/domains/example.com`, mail is forwarded to the address given, otherwise it defaults to the "postmaster" address as a catch-all.

I'd like to be able to specify multiple destination addresses so that, for example, mail sent to postmaster@example.com would be forwarded to both me@gmail.com and kittens@aol.com. I tried using a comma-separated list and listing the user twice with different addresses, and in both cases it only forwarded to the first address.

Does lsearch provide a way to do something like this already? If not, is there a way I could modify my configuration to allow it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to do me@gmail.com,user2@example.com, that should work.

Comment: @Todd I did a little more testing, and it turns out you're correct. I was using 2 test addresses that both forwarded to the same Gmail account, and didn't realize Gmail filtered out the duplicates, so I only saw one. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of expanding an alias to a different email address is not limited to a single address.  Exim accepts a comma separated list and will route each email address separately.  The format that you tried where it was comma-separated should work.

```
usera: me@gmail.com,user2@example.com
```